# How do I abstract out loop details for identical types in Go?

Tags: go

I have the following type:

```
type entity struct {
    components []Component
}

func NewEntity(componentsLength ComponentType) Entity {
    return &entity{
        components: make([]Component, componentsLength),
    }
}
```

When coding, I noticed the following repeated pattern:

```
func (e *entity) HasComponent(components ...Component) bool {
    for _, c := range components {
        if e.components[c.Type()] == nil {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func (e *entity) HasAnyComponent(components ...Component) bool {
    for _, c := range components {
        if e.components[c.Type()] != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Go seems okay with a lot of duplicated code when you're writing similar functions for different types. However, in this case the types are the same. I'm still having trouble refactoring the code to generalize the use of the `for` loop and `if` statement.

How can I refactor these functions so that the list handling is common, but the boolean operators and values are abstracted out? And should I?

Comment: Oh wow - Ignore my comment that was meant for a completely different question :/

Comment: Do you want to refactor methods that consist of *a single simple for loop?* If that's the only thing that's bothering you in the code, that must be a damn good code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the loop will appear in more places as I add the functionality I've planned. And if not, this would still be a valuable experience for me as I'm learning Go.

Comment: What you want for this sort of small reuse is functional programming. I will put a code example later but I would not be surprised if go has some FP like libs to help.

Comment: @Adam Gent: The problem, as I understood it, is that Go doesn't have generics, so anything that deals with different types isn't really possible (if it isn't reflected = slow).

Comment: Both those loops could be done with a `func ForComponents(loopBody func(*Component), comps ...Component) (result, finished bool)`. (I recall jQuery's `.each()` might work something like that, with a return value used to cut off the iteration early.) Minor challenge is that your wrapper function's type depends on what information each run of the loop returns, so you need different functions for different return values. Larger challenge is that `ForComponents(func(c *Component) (result, finished bool) { ... }, components...)` is longer than `for _, c := range components { ... }`.

Comment: ...so I think writing the loop out each time is just the best way to do it. I do agree with Michael Laszlo that a `map[foo]bool` might be handy to have here, since you're doing what look like membership tests, but I don't know the larger picture of your app.

Comment: A corrected and maybe slightly better `ForComponents` is at http://play.golang.org/p/4W99c_sVm8 -- but I still think just writing out loops (and maybe using a `map` if membership checks are core to what you're doing) is the way to go.

Comment: This code is already easy to understand and simple. Sure you can abstract it to avoid writing a for-loop twice, but it's going to make your code worse.

Comment: As @twotwotwo suggested, you could refactor it to have a function/method containing the `for` loop and call the jobs to be done specified in different functions, but that will not make your code more compact, nor make it more efficient, nor make it easier to understand and maintain. You do not need to optimize out simple `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you should refactor this code, not merely to make it more compact, but to better express the set-theoretical nature of the operations you're performing. Both functions are asking a question about the intersection of `e.components` and `components`.

What you're essentially saying with `HasComponent`—which should probably be called `HasAllComponents`—is that the intersection of `e.components` and `components` is equal to `components`. In other words, the size of the intersection is the same as the size of `components`.

As for `HasAnyComponent`, what you're saying is that the size of the intersection is at least one.

Both functions can be expressed succinctly by testing the size of the intersection, which you can obtain with, say, a function that has this signature:

```
func (e *entity) CountComponents(components ...Component) int
```

However, your original code has short-circuit logic that stops looking at further components once it knows the answer. You can incorporate such a short-circuited loop into a function with this signature:

```
func (e *entity) HasMinimumComponents(minimum int, components ...Component) bool
```

In the loop, increment a `count` variable whenever `e.components[c.Type()] != nil`. Return `true` as soon as `count >= minimum`.

Now you can efficiently implement `HasAllComponents` with a one-line body:

```
return entity.HasMinimumComponents(len(components), components...)
```

And the body of `HasAnyComponent` becomes:

```
return entity.HasMinimumComponents(1, components...)
```

Below is a program that implements this idea with slightly different data types. I defined a more abstract kind of `Entity` that contains a `map[int]bool`. You should have no trouble adapting the idea to your own program.

```go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Entity struct {
        ValueMap map[int]bool
}

func MakeEntity(values ...int) *Entity {
        entity := Entity{map[int]bool{}}
        for _, value := range values {
                entity.ValueMap[value] = true
        }
        return &entity
}

func (entity *Entity) HasMinimumValues(minimum int, values ...int) bool {
        count := 0
        if minimum == 0 {
                return true
        }
        for _, value := range values {
                if entity.ValueMap[value] {
                        count++
                        if count >= minimum {
                                return true
                        }
                }
        }
        return false
}

func (entity *Entity) HasAllValues(values ...int) bool {
        return entity.HasMinimumValues(len(values), values...)
}

func (entity *Entity) HasAnyValue(values ...int) bool {
        return entity.HasMinimumValues(1, values...)
}

func main() {
        entity := MakeEntity(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
        fmt.Printf("%t\n", entity.HasAllValues(3, 9))
        fmt.Printf("%t\n", entity.HasAllValues(3, 9, 12))
        fmt.Printf("%t\n", entity.HasAnyValue(9, 12, 15))
        fmt.Printf("%t\n", entity.HasAnyValue(12, 15))
}
```

Comment: You've unified the if statement and for loop, but this is now more code than before and is harder to understand. Duplication is best avoided, but so too are complexity and abstraction.

Comment: Agree that abstraction you don't need has a cost. I think it's useful to have all the options out there, but app authors should think hard about what they need to get the task done.